# How to create a colorbox with only one rounded corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes, colorbox

is there any posibility of creating a coloured text box with only one rounded corner? (Maybe using tikz)

[image: Shape]

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

`tcolorbox` can be your new friend:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    sharp corners, 
    rounded corners=northeast,
    colback=green!35!brown,
    colframe=green!35!brown,
    arc=5mm,
    text width=.85cm
]
\color{white}Test
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very nice and new solution (+1)! Good to know it.