# Mdframed with round corner only in the top

Tags: pdftex, mdframed

I am using `mdframed` box, my problem is, when I use the value "roundcorner=5pt", the round corner is  applied on all sides, I need it in the only the top `()`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
    backgroundcolor=yellow,
        roundcorner=5pt,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=green
        
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{Frame}[with Title]
    Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
\end{Frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you mind switching to tcolorbox instead of mdframed? With the former, you could use the approach shown here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334704/134144

Comment: @leandriis tcolorbox  have breaking issue

Comment: What kind of breaking issues?

Comment: @leandriis page overfull

Comment: Tcolorbox also offers means to allow a colored box to break across pages. Take a look at the breakable option.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you want because your code didn't work for me, but something like this (and much more) can be done with `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{Frame}[2][]{%
    enhanced, breakable,
    title={#2},
    colback=yellow,
    colbacktitle=green,
    sharp corners=south,
    arc=5pt,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
Text
    \begin{Frame}{with title}
    Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
    \newline Text
\end{Frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `mdframed` itself you can set rounded corners, set `bottomline=false` and draw the bottom line yourself without rounded corners using the `secondextra` key. With this key you can specify extra (e.g., TikZ) instructions for the final part of the frame.

Drawing a line at the bottom can be done with `\path[draw=black,line width=0.5pt] (O)--(O-|P);`, which I adapted from the file `md-frame1.mdf` that contains TikZ code for `mdframed`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{Frame}[1][]{%
    \begin{mdframed}[%
        frametitle={#1},
        skipabove=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        skipbelow=\baselineskip plus 2pt minus 1pt,
        linewidth=0.5pt,
        frametitlerule=true,
        backgroundcolor=yellow,
        roundcorner=5pt,
        frametitlebackgroundcolor=green,
        bottomline=false,
        secondextra={\path[draw=black,line width=0.5pt] (O)--(O-|P);}
    ]%
}{%
    \end{mdframed}
}
\begin{document}
Text
\begin{Frame}[with Title]
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{Frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]